# How to auto fill foreign key column value in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on laravel 5.2 and also beginner of laravel. I have `users` and `clients` table in the database. `user` field of clients table stores the value of `id column(primary key) of users table`. i.e, one user have many clients and one client belongs to one user. Now come to problem. When I'm going to insert new client of the logged in user, I'm getting error. No any error message. I searched and come to know that perhaps it happens because of foreign key column name is `user`, not `user_id`. So I updated my Client model from `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` to `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user');`. But still failed. If any one knows the answer, answer will be appreciated. Here is my code.

**ClientController (Try 1)**

```
$request->user()->clients()->create([
    'user' => $request->user()->id,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'age' => $request->age
]);
```

**ClientController (Try 2)**

```
$request->user()->clients()->create([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'age' => $request->age
]);
```

**Client Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Ak\Scopes\AgeScope;

class Client extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new AgeScope);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user');
    }

}
```

**User Model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'country'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected  $date = ['deleted_at'];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'user');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the relationship or the function in your user model. i guess that is where the problem is originating from. And/Or add this $fillable = ['email', 'age', 'user_id']; to your clients model.

Comment: @oseintow, it is added now in question.

Comment: sorry your relationship is wrong. and moreover you are using $request->user()->clients() instead of $request->user()->client(). the client in your relationship is singular. the client function body should be return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'user_id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem is Solved**

Problem is solved as I have to write `public $timestamps = false;` in Client Mode. After it, I don't need to insert `user` value manually. Because laravel is doing that task itself as I have write foreign key in User and Client Models relationship. i.e, `return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'user')` and `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user')` manually.

I can't understand that what should I do for this feature of laravel. Should I cry or laugh?

Answer (score 3):

sorry your relationship is wrong. and moreover you are using

```
 $request->user()->clients()
```

instead of

```
  $request->user()->client()
```

the client in your relationship is singular. And the client function body should be

```
  return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'user');
```

and in your client model add

```
 $fillable = ['email', 'age', 'user'];
```

and change the user function in your client model to

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user');
}
```

the orm should be like this

```
$request->user()->client()->create([
   'user' => $request->user()->id,
   'email' => $request->email,
   'age' => $request->age
]);
```

Comment: there is no any user_id column in clients table. And if I'm putting `user` instead of `user_id`, it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the foreign key in the clients table. list all the columns for the clients table

Comment: `id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
user int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
email varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
age int(11) NOT NULL,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `clients_user_foreign (user);`, `ALTER TABLE clients
MODIFY id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`, `ALTER TABLE clients ADD CONSTRAINT clients_user_foreign FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

Comment: I have updated as you told first time with `user` instead of `user_id`. But still no happiness.

Comment: Bdw nice suggestion as I come to know that what is mean to `$request->user()->client()`

Comment: Now I think issue is related to `create()` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103840/discussion-between-akshay-vaghasiya-and-oseintow).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `protected $fillable = ['email', 'age'];` to your Client model.

[More on mass assignement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Edit:
try this

Routes:

```
Route::post('user/{user}/client', 'YourController@store');
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, User, $user){
    $user->client()->create([
       'user' => $request->user()->id,
       'email' => $request->email,
       'age' => $request->age
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why you're calling ->user() from $request. Try initiating the user first (example: $user = User::find(id)) and calling `$user->clients()->create($client_array)`

Comment: I have tried this too as it is mentioned in laravel official docs. But non of these two works for me.

Comment: Do you also have `clients() {return $this->hasMany(User::class);}` in User model? Otherwise I'm slowly running out of ideas.

Comment: Yes. It is in User Model.  `public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
    }`

Comment: As I also tried these too. `public function client() { return $this->hasMany('App\Client', 'user');`

Comment: This is how I would make this:
Routes:
    Route::post('user/{user}/client', 'YourController@store');
Controller:
    public function store(Request $request, User $user){
        $user->clients()->create([
           'user' => $request->user()->id,
           'email' => $request->email,
           'age' => $request->age
        ]);
    }

Comment: It's nice. But then what is the meaning of using laravel if I will ignore functionality given by laravel itself? So I don't want to go for alternate way. I just want to deal with the current way.